# Enumerator behavior changes based on how we reference it?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Wrapping a reference to the list's enumerator inside a class seems to change its behavior.  Example with an anonymous class:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    var an = new { E = list.GetEnumerator() };
    while (an.E.MoveNext())
    {
        Debug.Write(an.E.Current);
    }
}
```

I would expect this to print "123", but it only prints zero and never terminates.  The same example with a concrete class:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    var an = new Foo()
    {
        E = list.GetEnumerator()
    };

    while (an.E.MoveNext())
    {
        Debug.Write(an.E.Current);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public List<int>.Enumerator E { get; set; }
}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested it and for me it does not work with your concrete class either.

The reason is that `List<T>.Enumerator` is a **mutable** `struct` and `an.E` is a **property**.

The compiler generates a backing field for each auto-property like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<int>.Enumerator _E;
    public List<int>.Enumerator get_E() { return E; }
    public void set_E(List<int>.Enumerator value) { E = value; }
}
```

A `struct` is a value-type, so every-time you access `an.E` you get a **copy** of that value.

When you call `MoveNext()` or `Current`, you call it on **that copy** and this copy is mutated.

The next time you access `an.E` to call `MoveNext()` or `Current` you get a **fresh copy of the not-yet-iterated enumerator**.

And `an.E.Current` is `0` instead of `1` because - again - you get a fresh enumerator that `MoveNext()` was not yet called upon.

---

If you want to store a **reference** of the list's enumerator you could declare your class `Foo` with a property of type `IEnumerator<int>`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerator<int> E { get; set; }
}
```

If you assign `E = list.GetEnumerator();` now, the enumerator gets boxed and a *reference* instead of a *value* is stored.

Comment: using a public field in `Foo` does fix the problem. Nice.

Comment: @Jonesopolis yes, of course. By using a field you access the value (the struct) directly, the property returns a copy.

Comment: I'm on board with your answer